How can I traverse up and down lines contained in a gap buffer?
I'm writing a text editor as an exercise and I'm using a gap buffer as the data structure for holding text. For a cursor, I'm just storing an index into the buffer. Here is what I'm working with:
typedef struct
{
    char *buffer;
    size_t gap_start;
    size_t gap_end;
    size_t buffer_size;
} GapBuffer;

size_t cursor_position;

From the position of the cursor, I can perform all the basic operations on the buffer just fine (move left/right, insert, delete, shift the gap, expand/shrink the gap, etc.). However, I'm having issues implementing line-by-line movement - in particular determining the position of the cursor in the new line.
A lot of articles seem to only cover the basic operations of the gap buffer, and not so much the utilization of it. I found this implementation, which calculates and stores the positions of the newlines in the gap buffer so it can reference them to move the cursor up and down. However, this implementation is O(n), which seems slow compared to the speed of the other operations of the gap buffer.
I've attempted to implement other iterative solutions to this by scanning the buffer to the left/right of the cursor attempting to position the cursor on the correct "line" and in the correct "column", but all of my attempts have missed some edge case or fail due to data left in the gap after a previous shift or delete.
Is there some general solution for this? Given the amount of text editors/gap buffer implementations, there has to be some accepted way of moving the cursor in this fashion. Any advice is appreciated.

Don't use a buffer gap design in the first place? Use an array or linked list of lines.

... possibly using a gap buffer for each line if you're enamored of that data structure.

Note also that you may be underestimating the asymptotic complexity of gap buffer usage.  In particular, moving the cursor n positions right or left involves moving n characters from one side of the gap to the other.  That's O(n) too.

Of course, "all of my attempts have missed some edge case or fail due to data left in the gap after a previous shift or delete" in no way implies that such an approach cannot work.  Naturally you have to disregard everything in the current gap when you analyze the buffer contents, but as long as you do that correctly, I don't see any major impediment.

@JohnBollinger Or, do linked-list/array for most lines and do gap buffer for current line (and/or a line above/below)?

Sure, @CraigEstey, that's plausible.  Perl is not the only language where there's more than one way to do it.
